# Checking if a form field is numeric while using Jquery to get its value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I'm doing this:

```
var phone = $("#phone").val();
```

Then I want to check if:

1) Phone contains only numbers

2) Phone contains at least 10 digits

But the problem is, from my experience, using `$("something").val()` 
returns it as a string so `isNaN()` fails. But I don't want use `parseInt()` either since it will change strings into numbers as well and then `isNaN()` will always pass.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression like this one:

```
if (phone.match(/^\d{10,}$/)) {
    // the input contains at least 10 digits
}
```

Comment: Thanks                                   !poskigfo;lksgf;lkg;lf'dkg;l;skfd grable to make 15 chars

Answer (score 1):

Like @Andrew said you can use reg ex to do the check like this.

```
var regExp = new RegExp("^"+pattern+"$","");
return regExp.test(value);
```

Place the above in a function and pass the patern into it to make it re-useable.

Replace pattern with the one that matches your requirements.  The one from @Andrew looks like it'll work.